# Do supply limits apply if you capture ships at a port?

Tags: game-of-thrones

In the situation where your armies are at supply limit, and you capture a territory that has ships in port, do you have to immediately disband armies, or you do you get to keep them until next supply round?

IMO it seems you should be allowed to keep them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you are not allowed to keep them if you are over your supply limit. From page 25:

> **Taking Control of Enemy Ports** - If the land area connected to a Port is successfully attacked and taken control of by another player, that player may immediately replace any enemy Ship units in the Port with an equal number of his own available Ship units (or as many Ship units as he has available, he desires, **or is allowed by supply limits**). **Excess enemy ships are simply removed from the board.**

Comment: It's also worth pointing out that you don't get to choose which armies are disband. It specifically says any ships that push you over the supply limit are the ones to be removed.